# prove the sequence converges and determine the limit

Tags: limits, analysis

$x_{n+1}$= $\frac{x_n+30}{6}$ where $x_1$=0

This is what I have:

$x_{1+1}$=$\frac{x_1+30}{6}$

$x_{2}$=$\frac{0+30}{6}$=5

but how do I show its converges and then find the limit of it?

Comment: Has your question been answered? If yes, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Prove that it is an increasing sequence and that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):x_n<6$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$x_{n+1} = 5+\frac{x_n}{6} = 5+\frac{1}{6}\left( 5+\frac{x_{n-1}}{6} \right) = 5 + \frac{5}{6}+\frac{5}{36}+\frac{x_{n-2}}{6^3}$$

One can notice a trend here, and it is easy to see that

$$x_{n+1} = 5+\frac{5}{6}+\cdots+\frac{5}{6^{n-1}}+\frac{x_1}{6^n}= 5\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^k+\frac{x_1}{6^n}=5\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^k$$

This can be shown by induction.

We see that $x_n$ is a geometric sum multiplied by a constant, and using the well-known formula for the sum of a geometric series, we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1} = 5 \cdot \frac{1}{1-1/6} = 6$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
If this sequence has a limit, it is a fixed point of the (continuous) function which defines the recurrence relation. The unique fixed point  is $6$.

Therefore, set $y_n=x_n-6$, deduce a recurrence relation for $y_n$ and show $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use induction to show that $x_n < 6,$ for all $n \geq 1.$ Then $x_{n+1} - x_{n} = 5 - \frac {5x_{n}} {6} > 0$ for all $n \geq 1,$ since $x_n < 6$ for all $n \geq 1.$ So $\{x_n \}$ is strictly increasing.